Pointwise convergence from an L^p convergence in the case where the limit is infinite
Let ${v_n}\subset L^p(\Omega)$ and suppose that $$|v_n|_p\longrightarrow +\infty,$$
as $n\longrightarrow +\infty$.
My question is the following: Can we ensure the existence of a subsequence of ${v_n}$, still denoted by ${v_n}$, such that $$|v_n(x)|\longrightarrow +\infty,$$
as $n\longrightarrow +\infty$ and for almost every $x\in\Omega$?
Thank you.
I have a sequence of functions in $L^p(\Omega)$ which is unbounded, that is, $$\displaystyle\lim_{n\longrightarrow +\infty} |v_n|_p=+\infty,$$
and I search if I can extract a subsequence so that $$|v_n(x)|\longrightarrow +\infty.$$
